# ASP.NET, Dependency Injection, Blazor and Async - SendAsync issue

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await, dependency-injection, blazor

Update: Seemed to be directly related to using my own HttpClient with SendAsync in ASP.NET I'm guessing. What special considerations do you have to take with your own web requests via HttpClient/Async while being in an ASP.NET "content". For now, I've switched the two calls I'm using to the non-async so I can finish my work for the day, but will revisit the correct DI tomorrow. Just curious why using your own HttpClient and making an Async call behaves differently?

First Question: I was trying to step through this code to detect the problem. But it always just skips to breaking on the PageTitle tag because @Person is null at the moment.
It goes into the first async call and never returns. Traced it a little further and it seems to make an HttpClient Async call get to get a token from backend service. And I can see in fiddler it gets a successful response. But doesn't come back from that async... just "jumps ahead".

Any good rules of thumb around using async in service-side Blazor?
Do you use ConfigureAwait(false) ? use it on any calls? New to Blazor's rendering model. But from the reading I did it seems like it will wait or its supposed to wait on things being non-null ?? Is registering services Scoped a good default rule of thumb? Is creating a fresh HttpClient instead of injecting it an issue? I've been trying to rule things out all morning. Uninstalled Mediatr and am just using the Handler as Service classe now.

Here is code sample of where things start going awry for me.

```
@page "/person/{personId:int}/{viewMode}"
@using Laz.Core.Blazor.Components
@using Laz.Project.Core.Domain.Models
@using Laz.Core.Domain.Handlers
@inject GetPersonHandler GetPersonHandler
@inject ILogger<PrintPerson> Logger

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int PersonId { get; set; } = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public string ViewMode { get; set; }

    public ApiPerson Person { get; set; } = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("OnInitializedAsync - Person Page");
        var req = new GetPersonRequest {PersonId = PersonId};
        Logger.LogInformation("1"); // after this it seems to get lost in async calls and jump to rendering which throws error. This is my first encounter with this issue.
        GetPersonResponse response = await GetPersonHandler.Handle(req, CancellationToken.None);
        Logger.LogInformation("2");
        Person = response.Person;
        Logger.LogInformation("3");
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
<PageTitle>{@Person.Name}</PageTitle>
```

Comment: Backing up @HH.  The rule with async is: Unless you're an async specialist, keep it simple - `async` and `await` are the only two verbs you need to know.

Comment: Try not to. It's like cancer from what I've seen. You use it in one place and it spreads to keep it working. But ... heck... being new to Blazor I tried it. Just needed to get through today, and I could have cleaned it up.

Comment: anything against doing a simple `<PageTitle>{@Person?.Name}</PageTitle>`? or another form of null check? It is by design for the page bindings to try to render while the async calls in `OnInitializedAsync` are still running and for good reason. You don't want to show the user's a white page while data is being loaded. You are expected to handle things like loading icons for this.

Comment: No objection. Just new to this. Any really good write-ups @NevilleNazerane on what is really going on "behind the scenes" with this? So I can better understand

Answer (score 2):

If I've read your code correctly, you haven't yet fully grasped the Component lifecycle, and have a null handling problem.  Review why there's a null check in the render code in `FetchData`.

In your code this line [which I believe from your update is a HttpClient request] yields control back to the caller of `OnInitializedAsync` in the component code. This then renders the component for the first time, at which point:

```cs
<PageTitle>{@Person.Name}</PageTitle>
```

`Person` is null.

You can reproduce your problem in a simple MRE.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>@_model.Title</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private Model? _model = null;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        _model = new Model() { Title="Hello" };
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you want to initialize variables as null, the solution is to handle nulls gracefully:

```cs
<PageTitle>@(Person?.Name ?? "Not Set")</PageTitle>
```

PS Did you see a possible null reference warning on `Person.Name`?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I'm still running into weird Async stuff. Like one behavior when I step through code. One where I just let it run. Sync issues. Async issues. Going to take a fresh look in the AM. Been a 14 hour day for me.

Comment: How well does it line up to React's lifecycle? The only reason I tried certain troubleshooting steps was reading that it didn't let through things before they were "baked", but in hindsight I can see how they would have to deal with this... like any other async framework.

Comment: Humans are too slow for async debugging!  I do lots of writes to console to see what sequence things are happening in.   See this article for a MS view on async  Do you like your breakfast hot or cold - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/

Comment: Mr C, I'm just starting to roll off a huge React project where console.log was my friend and enemy. I really didn't like React's functional model with hooks. Some easier model with inheritance and I could have been done in 1/6 of the time. Really enjoying Blazor so far. Only been hit with a few gotchas. But nothing like the Hook madness in Camp React.

Comment: Most of Blazor is standard DotNetCore.  Components are new, and take a lot of getting used to.  Ask away on here if you get puzzled.